# Drupal update modules and core strategy

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, updates

I would like to know where can i find or whats the official process to consider when you have to update both the modules and the core in a Drupal 7 site at same time.

I mean, what do i have to update first?
Modules then Core, Core then modules or it doesn't matter at all or it depends of each module documentation?

Also i would like to know if this process changed in Drupal 8.

I have found the process to update each one but not together.

I always do modules then core, but if you have a good reference or any article with a justification for this will be better to understand why.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I would suggest you to use drush commands to upgrade core version. It will take care of the rest. But if you want to do manually then you can continue reading below answer.

1. In my opinion you have to update the core first ( if there is latest core and the core required modules available ) and then you can update other modules i.e contrib modules. At the end custom modules based on compatibility.
2. After placing the latest code you can use drush updb or {your domain}/update.php to update your database.

Or else you can do it in the following way:

Download latest drupal code, place your custom code inside it and use the old database and then run update. This is not the correct way but sometimes it works.

Note: Before doing any of the steps above always work in local environment and keep a backup. Never try it on production.

Thanks

Comment: Tyvm. The only way i can update is manually, so i needed to know this. I really apreciate your help. And sorry if my question is a noob question but if I don't ask I'll never know.